# Maven is not running any tests called using testng suitexml files in POM.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, maven

I am trying to run a test using Maven by providing the testng.xml file. It is not running any test, although the build is successful.

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sawanttech</groupId>
    <artifactId>LearningSelenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>LearningSelenium</name>
    <url>https://learningselenium.com</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.testSource>1.8</maven.compiler.testSource>
        <maven.compiler.testTarget>1.8</maven.compiler.testTarget>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Regression</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="3">
  <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="testing.TestAB"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**TestAB.java**

```
package testing;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestAB
{
    @Test
    public void ab()
    {
        System.out.println("ab test method called");
    }
    
}
```

**Output:**

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.885 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-12T20:03:20+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help.

**Edit:**
**Added console message after fix was provided by Tibor Digana to fail the build and state the actual message for tests not being run:**

```
D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium>mvn test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.sawanttech:LearningSelenium >-------------------
[INFO] Building LearningSelenium 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ Learning
Selenium ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ LearningSelen
ium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @
LearningSelenium ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 31 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Learn
ingSelenium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ LearningSelenium
 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[ERROR] Suite file D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium\src\test
\resources\testng.xml is not a valid file
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.164 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-08T21:58:12+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.
0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project LearningSelenium: There are test failures.

[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium\tar
get\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].
dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium\src\test
\resources\testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was
an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium\src\test
\resources\testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.for
k(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run
(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run
(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute
Provider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute
AfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute
(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo
(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Mojo
Executor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Mojo
Executor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Mojo
Executor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.bu
ildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.bu
ildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.Si
ngleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(
LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305
)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192
)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMet
hodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhan
ced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Laun
cher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExi
tCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launch
er.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Comment: Hi. Are you using this command to run test : mvn clean install test

Comment: Yes. I am running mvn clean install test.

Comment: I am having same issue, but reading through the comments i am not getting in which file need to to put changes to print the error? Can you please help me here Note: I was not able to comment to original thread because of having low reputation for comments.

Comment: You will get this error when your testng.xml file is not in the project root directory and you have passed `<suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>` which means it will look for the testng.xml file in the project root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Surefire configuration, I guess the file **src/test/resources/testng.xml** does not exist. Pls post the project on GitHub. It's hard to investigate like this.

I believe this issue is similar to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277490/getting-testng-xml-is-not-a-valid-file-error-in-jenkins/61398744#61398744).

Comment: This issue is resolved by placing the testng.xml file at the root directory of the project instead of src/test/resources and using `<suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>` in POM file.

Comment: Hi Sandesh, I am the Apache developer and I want to provide a fix. or more information pls see the JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1885

Comment: It would be good if it is fixed by stating the actual reason for tests not being run. Please let me know what information you want.

Comment: The test do not run because the XML file is not found (wrong place). Imagine your project apperas in /home/sandesh and the XML file appears in /home/sandesh/src/test/resources/testng.xml and then the config must be <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>. Similarily we can print such a hint in the error but the sanity check must crash in the plugin and then the user has to understand the error and shift the XML file to the right place.

Comment: Do you want me to run this testcase ?

Comment: Yes, feel free to try out.

Comment: I just ran this testcase "mvn test" using maven compiler plugin version 3.8.1 and maven surefire plugin version 3.0.0-M5. Previously, the build was shown as SUCCESS despite 0 tests being run and now it is shown as FAILURE with 0 tests run which is good. The error message is : `[ERROR] Suite file D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium\src\test\resources\testng.xml is not a valid file`.

Comment: But I think the error message stating "file is missing" instead of "file is not valid" would be more appropriate because "file is not valid" indicates that the file is available at the given directory, but it is not in valid format. Also, this error message is repeated twice. I have added the console message in the original post.

Comment: This message is printed directly by the TestNG library. The Surefire plugin is not able to change the text. Our Surefire documentation for TestNG provider gives you the opportunity to controle TestNG's logger via a system property but that's maximum how to avoid it.
[ERROR] Suite file D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium\src\test
\resources\testng.xml is not a valid file
The maximum the Surefire can do is to provide a message in the Exception saying that the "file is missing". We have to include the original TestNG messages in the Exception too.

Comment: If the message "file is not valid" is bad for you, please ask the TestNG team to fix their message on GH: https://github.com/cbeust/testng

Comment: Thanks for this fix to fail the build and print the actual reason.